# AWS DRS boto3 start_recovery is not returning recovery_instance ID in response

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, drs

I am working on aws drs using boto3. I have created a script, that will execute and return an output. But as per aws boto3 documentation it should also return '**recoveryInstanceID**'. I am receiving everything except the recoveryInstanceID.
Code for your reference:

```
import boto3


myclient = boto3.client('drs'

source_server = 's-32fe7############'

response = myclient.start_recovery(
    isDrill=True,
    sourceServers=[
        {
            'sourceServerID': source_server
        },
    ],
)

print(response)
```

As per documentation, output should be:

[image]

But I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Your RDS instance does not have recovery instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved. I tried by initiating a drill with boto3 start_recovery method. Then I took recovery_instance_id from describe_recovery_instances method. Which takes source server as input and returned recovery_instance_ID associated with it.